# Regex accept Unicode only

Tags: java, regex, unicode

Hi everyone i need to make a regex with the following requirements:

Alphanumeric
Can include any valid Unicode characters, including spaces or punctuation, although we shouldn't permit leading or trailing spaces.

```
^[\\p{S}\\p{L}\\d\\p{P}][\\p{L}\\d\\p{P} ]{4,18}[\\p{L}\\d\\p{P}]$
```

Right now I'm using this one but isn't working properly for some unicode characters like: §

I'm not a pro with the regex so I'm asking for some help thanks.

Comment: You'll need to define "any valid Unicode character".  Are you looking to avoid Unicode not-a-character code points?  Are you trying to avoid orphaned surrogates?  Or does "any" really mean characters belonging to one of a few particular character classes that you haven't specified?

Comment: Any valid unicode character means every character that is in the unicode table.

Comment: The point being that Java `String`s already consist of Unicode text encoded in UTF-16.  Java `char`s that are not in the Unicode surrogate code point range are all valid Unicode characters.  Surrogate pairs also correspond to Unicode code points, though large spaces of such code points have no character assigned to them.

Comment: There is no single Unicode table.  Do you then mean code points to which Unicode maps a character?  Do you mean to include tabulated code points explicitly designated to not correspond to any character?  Do you need to account for characters outside the BMP, which will be represented in Java as surrogate pairs?

Comment: And when you say leading and trailing spaces must not be present, it looks like you may mean that in the sense of characters that Unicode considers whitespace, as opposed to just literal space characters, or characters that *Java* considers whitespace.  So which is it?

Comment: Furthermore, you've been a bit inconsistent.  "Alphanumeric" normally means consisting of letters and / or digits, which seems to agree with your regex, but you also say you want to match *any* Unicode character, and give as an example one that is neither a letter nor a digit.  So which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are permitting absolutely everything except trailing or leading spaces, then maybe you don't need a regex:

```
boolean valid = !string.startsWith(" ") && !string.endsWith(" ");
```

If you meant trailing or leading *whitespace*, try:

```
boolean valid = string.trim().equals(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression ...

```
^(?:[^\p{Z}\p{Cc}](?:.*[^\p{Z}\p{Cc}]))$
```

... matches Java `String`s that neither start nor end with a character in Unicode category Z (spacing characters) or Cc (control characters).  It will match the empty string; it could be simplified a bit if it should not do so.  It will accept unpaired surogates, though they could be excluded by a more complicated regex if that is needed.  It will accept unmapped BMP code points and surrogate pairs corresponding to unmapped supplemental code points, and I do not think it is possible to exclude those generically.